# Use Oracle User Defined Type with Hibernate - Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, user-defined-types

I want to use hibernate (spring jpa) to call stored procedure. In my stored procedures there are user defined types (udt) (in or out params).

In hibernate example, I see there is refcur parameter mode but I cant find something about udt parameter types in Oracle. How can I call the stored procedure with user defined types? Can someone share any sample?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE      SP_DEMO_SP
   (
    code        IN NUMBER,
    myudt        OUT mytype 
     )
TYPE mytype AS OBJECT
(
   name VARCHAR2 (100),
   food_group VARCHAR2 (100),
);
```

what I want something like or another way..

```
StoredProcedureQuery query=entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery().registerStoredProcedureParameter(ParameterMode.UDT)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I wrote it hibernate forum and as I understand there is no way,you have to change your code cursor or you have to use spring jdbc